# What is the "state value" of a PID?

Tags: pid-controller

I have a Yudian 518 PID installed in a heat treatment furnace and it has two segment displays labeled PV (process value) and SV (state value). The process value for my instrument is obviously the current measured temperature inside the furnace. At first I thought the "state value" was supposed to be the time, but it is going up too slowly for it to be time in seconds.

So, is this value like some of kind of target value? In other words, the PID has computed what temperature it wants the kiln to have (according to the heating program) and the state value is this target value. At least that's my best guess. What is it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller

Comment: @user263983 Can you send me a link to MIT's student application form, too, so I can get a degree in electrical engineering to understand it? Thanks.

Comment: No, I can not. From manual of that device SV is set point. To better understand it learn chinese. Just Google for manual for your device. It is on page 20.

Comment: Is the number on the `SV` display changing automatically ?

Comment: Could it be the output of the PID, ie the control signal that goes to the heater?

Comment: Can you post a user manual link ? A user manual I found doesn't say anything about `state value` only `set point`.

Answer (score 2):

As you are probably figuring out, your question isn't "what is the 'state value' of **a** PID", but "what is the 'state value' of **my** PID".  At which point we can only guess.

My guess is that -- if it is not, indeed, the set value -- it is either the PID output, or the value of the integrator term.

Comment: The question is as stated, the state value of a PID. I am sorry I even mentioned the model I had since that seems to have become a distraction.

Comment: Clarify your question, then, and remove the bits where you're asking advise about a particular controller.  The phrase "What is the 'state value' of a PID" is meaningless in typical usage.  A PID controller can have states (plural), but what those are depend on the implementation.

Comment: @TylerDurden in that case the answer is much easier — there's no such thing :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the AI-518**P**, it is a ramp and soak type programmable controller and you can expect SV (**setpoint**) to vary during (and according to) the program that is entered into the controller.

Normally for a heat-treat oven you would want to follow such a time-temperature profile and therefore I expect you have the "P" version. Ramp and soak controllers do something like this (image from [[here]](https://www.eurotherm.com/temperature-control-applications/ramp-and-soak-applications/)()):

[image]

When you start the controller it may measure the temperature at the beginning and adjust the setpoint from there. In any case, SV (Set Value) should display the current setpoint and PV should display the current actual temperature (Process Variable)

Comment: Well, that is not happening. The SV value fluctuates as it runs, as I said in my question.

Comment: Perhaps the controller is defective.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual of the controller, SV refers to the set-point, i.e. the temperature you *want*.

Screen shot from manual:
[image]

Comment: No, that is only when the unit is being programmed. When the unit is running, it means the "state value". When the unit is running the SV value fluctuates and has no obvious relation to the programmed values.

Answer (score 0):

SV is the *set value* aka set-point. I.e. the target temperature.

If there is a ramp/soak sequence, or rate limit on set-point, the SV display could also slowly change to indicate this.

Ramp rates and soak times would be particularly relevant in a heat teatment application.

Comment: As per my comment below. SV stands for "state value", not set point. The SV display is indeed used to enter set points in this particular controller, but that is a secondary use of the display and has nothing to do with the values shown when the PID is running.

Comment: Interesting... It may be the output level, the other useful piece of information that would be of general interest to an operator, but I doubt it a little. Could it be just indicating a ramp? Updated answer for this.